# Как сохранить скрытые поля внутри сообщения в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, laravel

В web-приложении на laravel 5.3 + mysql есть чат. Каждое сообщение в этом чате на данный момент простой текст и хранится в поле типа `text`.

Я хочу добавить возможность упоминать в сообщении другого пользователя через символ `@`.

Например, текст сообщения для пользователя может выглядеть так:

```
Привет, @Иван.
```

В таком случае пользователь с ником Иван получит уведомление о новом сообщении даже если он оффлайн (по email).

Проблема в том, что имена не уникальны и я не могу сделать простое

```
 select email from users where username = 'Иван'
```

чтобы отправить сообщение на почту.

Действительно уникальны только id пользователей.

Один из вариантов хранения сообщения в базе

```
Привет, [user_id=3648].
```

Тогда на бэкенде перед тем как отобразить сообщение в браузере пользователя нужно будет распарсить строку, чтобы преобразовать ее в нужный вид (подставить @Иван вместо [user_id=3648])

Это опять же не лучший подход. В браузере тоже нужно городить огород на js, чтобы отправлять сообщение на сервер в нужном виде.

Какие есть подходы для решения этой задачи? Как (хотя бы приблизительно) это сделано в соц. сетях?

Answer (score 0):

Если юзер просто напишет

> Привет, @Иван.

то я лично не вижу способа узнать, какого из многочисленных Иванов он имеет в виду.

> на бэкенде перед тем как отобразить сообщение в браузере пользователя нужно будет распарсить строку, чтобы преобразовать ее в нужный вид (подставить @Иван вместо [user_id=3648])

Это ещё зачем? сообщение хранится в БД, пара (ID-имя) тоже, так что прямо в запросе никто не мешает выполнить нужные парсинг и подстановку прямо на стороне сервера БД.

Comment: Юзер не просто напишет `@Иван`, с сервера подтянутся возможные имена пользователей, из которых он выберет нужные (возможно несколько), а в базе сохранится что-то типа "Привет, [user_id=1] и [user_id=2]", что для пользователя будет выглядеть как "Привет, `@Иван` и `@Петя`.

Comment: Тогда не вижу проблемы... единственное зримое дополнение - шаблонная вставка должна быть такой, чтобы пользователь в принципе не мог ввести её в качестве текста сообщения. Ведь сейчас, встретив в тексте фрагмент `[user_id=3648]`, ты не имеешь возможности определить, это введено пользователем или вставлено кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Если имена не уникальны, то конкретного адресата определить не получиться. Либо отправлять сообщение всем Иванам, либо придумать способ идентифицировать конкретного. Например:
1. Указывать не имя, а логин (но он должен быть однозначно уникален), и в самом чате переходит к отображению имени в виде "Имя (Логин)", чтобы пользователь мог увидеть логины своих чатовцев.
2. При вводе "@Ив" в виде выпадающего списка отображать всех, чьи имена подходят под данную маску, и при вводе каждой следующей буквы список отсеивать, пока не останутся только Иваны. Но в данном подходе надо к имени отображать, например, фотографию, чтобы можно было различать разных Иванов. В финале тыкаем на верного Ивана и передаем его ИД в базу.

Но если у пользователей нет фотографии, то я вижу, как решение, только поиск по уникальным логинам.